# Zoho API V2 Update Record

Tags: php, json, zoho

I am trying to use the Zoho API Version 2 to do a simple record update in Leads. I am using PHP and CURL and my sample code for this call (to update a single field in the record) is as follows:-

```
$apiUrl = "https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads/" . {valid record id here};

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($fields),
    sprintf('Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken %s', {valid auth token here})
);

$fields = json_encode([["data" => ["City" => "Egham"]]]);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

No matter how I format the JSON, I always get the following returned:

```
{"code":"INVALID_DATA","details": {"expected_data_type":"jsonobject"},"message":"body","status":"error"}
```

It is not a matter of invalid auth tokens etc because I have successfully used PHP and CURL with the Zoho API to read data and I decode the JSON returned successfully.

Please could somebody help with passing valid JSON data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The above code constructs input `JSON` like this
`[{"data":{"City":"Egham"}}]`. This `JSON` is not valid as per the `ZOHO CRM APIs`([API help](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/v2/#update-specify-records)).

It should be like this `{"data":[{"City":"Egham"}]}`.

Change the code like this :

```
$apiUrl = "https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads/" . {valid record id here};

$fields = json_encode(array("data" => array(["City" => "Egham"])));

// *strlen must be called after defining the variable. So moved headers down to $fields*

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($fields),
    sprintf('Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken %s', {valid auth token here})
);


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks Sumanth - that fixed it! I think I tried this combination previously but there were other parts of the code that were wrong at the time which is why it didn't work then.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me and is so poorly documented with Zoho. Note also that one can use the [Search API](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v2/search-records.html) to lookup records by certain criteria such as email or phone in Leads, Contacts, or Accounts in order to get that record ID with `$oJSON->data[0]->id` if `$oJSON` is the object from a `json_decode` of the `$result`, should the `$result` have JSON data inside.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the data into JSON format:

```
import json
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```